# Crudrepository findBy function only works when nothing is found

Tags: java, spring, jpa

The first time I implemented the findByContentContaining function in the repository everyting worked fine. But now when I call the function and if it finds something, it gives me an error. If it doesn't find anything it returns an empty list.

This is my repository (everyting works except the findByContentContaining function):

```
public interface KweetRepo extends CrudRepository<Kweet, Integer> {

    Kweet getById(Integer id);

    List<Kweet> findTop10ByPosterId(int id);

    List<Kweet> findByContentContaining(String content);

    List<Kweet> findByPosterId(int id);

}
```

This is the model for my Kweet class

```
@Entity
public class Kweet implements Comparable<Kweet>{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="content")
    private String content;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private Date dateTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User poster;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="KweetLikedBy")
    private List<User> likedBy;

    public Kweet() {
    }

    public Kweet(String content, Date dateTime, User poster, List<User> likedBy) {
        this.content = content;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.poster = poster;
        this.likedBy = likedBy;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public int getPoster() {
        return poster.getId();
    }

    public void setPoster(User poster) {
        this.poster = poster;
    }

    public List<User> getLikedBy() {
        return likedBy;
    }

    public void addLikedBy(User user) {
        this.likedBy.add(user);
    }

    public void removeLikedBy(User user) {
        this.likedBy.remove(user);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Kweet o) {
        return getDateTime().compareTo(o.getDateTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: further which find by function gives you an error

Comment: It's an invocationtargetexception in the findByContentContaining function

Comment: can you post the stacktrace from the exception

Comment: Post the stacktrace as part of the question to help understand your problem

Comment: Do you have your Repository Interface annotated with @Repository?